# discord.js - guildMemberRemove doesn't work, guildMemberAdd works perfectly fine

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Sorry if this is poorly formatted, I've never written a question on here before.

First of all, this is my first time writing anything in JavaScript, so this might be some dumb mistake I'm making that's causing my problem.

What I want to do is send a message when a member joins the server, and send a different message when a member leaves. When someone joins the server, the join message is sent and everything works perfectly fine, but when a member leaves, absolutely nothing happens. I put in some console.logs in the joinMessage and leaveMessage functions, and I get an output for joinMessage but nothing for remove. I have enabled Presence Intent and Server Members Intent on the Discord developer portal.

The join and leave message functions are down at the bottom, but I went ahead and added the entire thing so people could help me better. The bot token and channel IDs have been removed, and they are correct in my version of the code.

```
console.log('Starting');

const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');
const commandHandler = require("./commands");
const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MEMBERS] });
client.login('token');
var server = client.guilds.cache.get('server');

client.on('ready', ready);
function ready()
{
    console.log('Authenticated');
    server = client.guilds.cache.get('server');
}

client.on('messageCreate', receivedMessage);
function receivedMessage(msg)
{
    commandHandler(msg);
}


client.on('guildMemberAdd', joinMessage);
function joinMessage(member)
{
    let channelWelcome = server.channels.cache.get('welcome');
    let channelIntro = server.channels.cache.get('intro');
    channelWelcome.send(`Welcome to the server, ${member}! Head over to ${channelIntro} and introduce yourself!`); 
}


client.on('guildMemberRemove', leaveMessage);
function leaveMessage(member)
{
    let channelWelcome = server.channels.cache.get('welcome');
    channelWelcome.send(`${member} has left the server.`); 
}
```

I've been trying to figure this out for about an hour, so I'd really appreciate it if someone could help me solve this. Thanks!

Comment: I see absolutely no flaws in the code whatsoever, just to check if the event is being emitted could you do something like `client.on("guildMemberRemove", (member) => { console.log("emitted"); }` ( you may do it with a basic function too but I just prefer arrow functions so yea...

Comment: I did that and I'm still not getting anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include following intent: `GUILD_PRESENCES`

So your code needs to look like this:

```
const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_PRESENCES, Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MEMBERS] });
```

Now your bot will detect if a member leaves the guild.

Answer (score 1):

Try calling the function directly in the event parameters. There might be some sort of confliction when extracting the function

```js
client.on("guildMemberAdd", (member) => {
    let channelWelcome = server.channels.cache.get('welcome');
    let channelIntro = server.channels.cache.get('intro');
    channelWelcome.send(`Welcome to the server, ${member}! Head over to ${channelIntro} and introduce yourself!`); 
}

client.on("guildMemberRemove", (member) => {
    let channelWelcome = server.channels.cache.get('welcome');
    channelWelcome.send(`${member} has left the server.`);
}
```

Also make sure you have set the right intents (if you are running V13), and gave the bot the correct privileged intents in the developer portal

Comment: Just tried it out and it still isn't doing anything. I enabled both privileged gateway intents on the developer portal and I enabled the GUILD_MEMBERS intent in my code, is there another one that I missed that's required for members leaving?

Answer (score 1):

This question/answer is rather old, but I found that the selected answer here is not fully correct, at least in the current version.

You do not in fact need the Presences Intent to receive `guildMemberRemove` event. The event is actually not firing in cases when the member data is not *cached* and will therefore not emit the event.

In order to resolve this, you will need to enable [Partials](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/partials.html#enabling-partials) on the client, specifically `Partials.GuildMember`. This will enable the event to emit on un-cached data.