# guildMemberRemove doesn't work unlike guildMemberAdd

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I don't know why "guildMemberRemove" is not activated when a member leaves the server.

Indeed, when I put a console.log("test"), it does not appear.

However, "guildMemberAdd" has no problem, and messages are send.

What should I change?

This is my code :

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client({
    intents: ["GUILDS", "GUILD_MESSAGES", "GUILD_MEMBERS", "GUILD_INVITES"]
});

const ID_NEW_MEMBER_CHANNEL = "943499711418093588";
const ID_LOG_CHANNEL = "942887622748037200";


client.on("ready", async () => {

    const logChannel = client.channels.cache.get(ID_LOG_CHANNEL);
    client.user.setPresence({
        activities: [{
            name: "Mario Sokoban"
        }]
    });

    console.clear();
    console.log("Nobody like you.")
});


client.on('guildMemberAdd', (member) => {

    const channel = client.channels.cache.get(ID_NEW_MEMBER_CHANNEL);
    const embedArrivee = [`L'incroyable ${member} est bien arrivé :partying_face::nerd:`, `Wow, ${member} est entré par effraction :dizzy_face::exploding_head:`, `Que vois-je ?! Un ${member} sauvage :partying_face::yum:`, `Le saviez-vous ? ${member} vient de se poser à bord :partying_face:`, `Est-ce un oiseau, un avion, une souris, ah non ! C'est ${member} qui se joint à nous :partying_face::grin:`, `Que tout le monde reste calme, ${member} est parmis nous :shushing_face::grimacing:`];
    const randomEmbed = embedArrivee[Math.floor(Math.random() * embedArrivee.length)];

    member.guild.invites.fetch().then(newInvites => {
        const oldInvites = invites.get(member.guild.id);
        const invite = newInvites.find(i => i.uses > oldInvites.get(i.code));
    });

    const bienvenue = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#88d4ef')
        .setDescription(randomEmbed)
        //.setFooter({ text: 'Merci <@' + invite.inviter.id + '> !'});

    channel.send({ embeds: [bienvenue] });
});


client.on('guildMemberRemove', (member) => {

    const channel = client.channels.cache.get(ID_NEW_MEMBER_CHANNEL);
    const embedExit = [`Oh non ! ${member} nous a quitté :cry:`, `Fatal Error : ${member} a disparu du serveur :cry:`, `Incroyable :dizzy_face: ${member} est parti sans payé ma bière :rage:`, `Commandant, j'ai raté ma cible. ${member} a disparu :cry:`, `Je crois que ${member} a disparu :cry:, mais le beau temps est revenu :sunglasses:`, `Mais c'est horrible :scream: ${member} est tombé de la falaise :scream:`];
    const randomEmbed = embedExit[Math.floor(Math.random() * embedExit.length)];

    const bye = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#88d4ef')
        .setDescription(randomEmbed)

    channel.send({ embeds: [bye] });
});


client.login("");
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69722447/5467710) answer your question?

Comment: Yes, it did. Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [discord.js - guildMemberRemove doesn't work, guildMemberAdd works perfectly fine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69021588/discord-js-guildmemberremove-doesnt-work-guildmemberadd-works-perfectly-fine)